# stringTo javascript

Tags: javascript

I am hoping that I can get some help with my learning and find out what it is about my function that is not working correctly:

```
function contains() {
 var substr = 'bar';
 var str = 'foobar';
  if (str.indexOf(substr)) {
   // Return true if substr is a substring of str
   return true;
  } else {
   // and false if substr is not a substring of str
   return false;
  };
 }
```

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help me get over this bump in learning.

Rob

Comment: str.indexOf(substr) > -1 (if string is not found, return -1)

Comment: You can make it shorter: `return str.indexOf(substr) > -1;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` returns `-1` if it's not found, and `~-1 === 0` is falsy. Every other number returns truthy with `~` (since all numbers other than `0` are truthy). `~` is the bitwise NOT which has an interesting property that `~-1 === 0`.

`!!` converts to a boolean (truthy becomes `true`, falsy becomes `false`).

So you could do:

```
function contains() {
  var substr = 'bar';
  var str = 'foobar';
  return !!~str.indexOf(substr);
}
```

You're currently returning `true` if it's not found (`-1` is thruthy), and `false` if it's at position `0` (`0` is falsy).

Answer (score 2):

it's kind of off the topic, but you can write some regex like:

```
function contains() {
    var str = 'foobar';
    var substrRegex = /bar/;
    return substrRegex.test(str);
}
```

about javascript `test()`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

about Regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/